# Apache access control -- from allow/deny to require

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm trying to move my Apache access control directives from the older Order, Allow, and Deny to the newer Require.  Unfortunately, I'm unable to think a new way after having used the old way for so long.

Basically, I'd like to deny access to everyone except a few IP addresses.  Using the old format, I had:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.123.123
Allow from 123.123.123.123
```

I *think* it should be something like:

```
Require all denied
Require ip 192.168.123.123
Require ip 123.123.123.123
```

This appears to work.

But I'm uncertain if I should be not think like the "old way".  Perhaps I should be using RequireAll or RequireAny some how, or even if I should nest them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Authorization Containers and Configuration Sections to set a default restriction and then provide access, for example:

```
<Directory "/">
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/path_to_document_root">
  <RequireAny>
    Require ip 192.168.123.123
    Require ip 123.123.123.123
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

For more information, read at least *all* of the [Apache documentation for the `authz_core` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require), and then also perhaps review the [Apache documentation for configuration sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html).

Comment: Ah!  I definitely wasn't even close to thinking it that way.  With this example, I've dive back into the documentation.  Personally, I found the examples in the Apache documentation to be either too simple or too hard -- not many that were "in the middle".  Thank you!